# java socket ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, tcp, objectinputstream

```
inStream = new ObjectInputStream(this.socket.getInputStream());
Packet rank = (Packet)inStream.readObject();
```

Hi, 
I supposed to receive an array from two clients. I can only receive from a client and prompt an error like this : Thanks in advance

```
 java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2338)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2822)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:804)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:301)
    at ServerGraph$Handler.run(ServerGraph.java:350)
```

Comment: Most likely the sending side write the object but didn't close() or even flush() the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I supposed to receive an array from two clients. I can only receive from a client and prompt an error like this
>
> ```
>  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
> ```

I think you may be misunderstanding how sockets work.  A socket represents a connection between one client and one server.  You seem to be saying that that you are expecting to get data from 2 different clients on a single `Socket`.  That is not possible.  It doesn't make sense.  You need a separate `Socket` for each client that your server is communicating with.

What you are seeing (the Connection reset) is explicable: the peer (i.e. the client or client's OS), has reset the connection for some reason.  The Java (?) client application might called `close()` or `shutdownOutput()`, or it might have just exited.

(You haven't shown us enough code to suggest the best way to fix your problem.  Are the sockets being opened by the clients or the server?)